# Rails production log file empty? (Ngnix + Passenger + Centos)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

My Rails app is running on a VPS using Ngnix and passenger, deployed using Capistrano, but the production.log in my log directory is empty.. Where are my Rails production logs??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if `rails_env production;` line added in your nginx config file:

   server {
           listen       80;
           server_name  localhost;

   ```
       #charset koi8-r;

       #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
       root /home/ubuntu/app_name/public;
       passenger_enabled on;
       rails_env production;

       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
           root   html;
       }
   ```
2. Remove `rails_12factor` gem if added in your gem file

   # group :production do

   #   gem 'rails_12factor'

   # end